# Excel Count Unique Values Whole Column e.g A:A

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm looking for a way to count unique values for the whole column (A:A).
Currently, I'm only able to write formulars like `A1:A10` which does the job. However, when changing to `A:A` is returns `#DIV/0`

The formulars I'm currently using are:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(A2:A607;A2:A607))
```

and

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH(A2:A607;A2:A607;0);MATCH(A2:A607;A2:A607;0))>0;1))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work

`=SUMPRODUCT((A:A<>"")/COUNTIF(A:A, A:A & ""))`

Comment: Did the job very well´. Thank you!

Comment: Mark the answer as correct then please. Though I feel like it bos the excel speed down a little (at least for me). Might be smoother to implement simply via pivot table.

Comment: I had to wait for 5 minutes before I was allowed to mark your answer. Yeah, agree upon the speed. However, the pivot table is not appropriate for me in this situation. Again thanks